# i cannot move lines vertices independent from other adjacent lines/vertices in my model

Tags: edges

I have a simple model and want to move some edges/lines etc. on one axise. Unfortunately Blender moves not only the selected line/edge and those which are directly connected but also nearby parallel edges from loops cuts. Same happens when I try to bevel. i dont want this. what do i have to do to only move selected lines/edges/vertices? Thank you.

Comment: do you have the proportional editing mode enabled? (blue sphere icon on the horizontal menu bar on the bottom of the 3D View)